# PayPal PHP-SDK: Create Amount Only Invoice

Tags: php, paypal

It's been hours trying to create an invoice using `PayPal PHP-SDK` to create an invoice using the `Amount Template` but with no success.

When I run this following code:

```
$invoice
    ->setMerchantInfo(new MerchantInfo())
    ->setBillingInfo(array(new BillingInfo()))
    ->setNote("Medical Invoice 16 Jul, 2013 PST")
    ->setReference('Ref: 200 OK')
    ->setTotalAmount(new Currency())
    ->setTemplateId('TEMP-9WT50262M1352140L');

$invoice->getTotalAmount()
    ->setValue(99)
    ->setCurrency('EUR');
// setting BillInfo, MerchantInfo, (...) here with no problems

dd($invoice);
```

I get the following desired output:

```
Invoice {#613 ▼
  -_propMap: array:16 [▼
    "merchant_info" => MerchantInfo {#627 ▶}
    "billing_info" => array:1 [▶]
    "note" => "Medical Invoice 16 Jul, 2013 PST"
    "reference" => "Ref: 200 OK"
    "total_amount" => Currency {#634 ▼
      -_propMap: array:2 [▼
        "currency" => "EUR"
        "value" => "99"
      ]
    }
    "logo_url" => "https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/i/logo/rebrand/ppcom.svg"
    "id" => "INV2-FL5F-MFLZ-EHSU-LR64"
    "number" => "0031"
    "template_id" => "TEMP-6HG30056XX0172355"
    "status" => "DRAFT"
    "invoice_date" => "2018-03-26 PDT"
    "tax_calculated_after_discount" => false
    "tax_inclusive" => false
    "metadata" => Metadata {#636 ▶}
    "allow_tip" => false
    "links" => array:6 [▶]
  ]
}
```

But when I run this at the end of the code:

```
try {
    $invoice->create($apiContext);
    dd($invoice);
}catch (PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getCode(); // Prints the Error Code
    echo $ex->getData(); // Prints the detailed error message 
    die($ex);
}catch (Exception $ex) {
    die($ex);
}
```

I get the following output:

```
// ...
    "total_amount" => Currency {#634 ▼
      -_propMap: array:2 [▼
        "currency" => "USD"
        "value" => "0.00"
      ]
    }
// ...
```

**NOTE:
I'm following this code: http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/invoice/CreateInvoice.html**

Why does it reset the currency and the value to USD and 0 (respectively)? What am I missing?

Notice: TemplateId used: `TEMP-9WT50262M1352140L <=> Amount`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've crawled the whole web searching for solutions but no success. So I kept reading the API classes and trying to understand how its setters and getters work.

On the official code sample provided by PayPal API team, the items are set as followed:

```
$items = array();
$items[0] = new InvoiceItem();
$items[0]
    ->setName("Sutures")
    ->setQuantity(100)
    ->setUnitPrice(new Currency());

$items[0]->getUnitPrice()
    ->setCurrency("USD")
    ->setValue(5);
```

On the class `PayPal\Api\InvoiceItem` you can set the `Unit of Measurement` which according to the API can be: `Amount`, `Quantity` or `Hours`. So I set the `Unit of Measurement` to `Amount` as followed:

```
$items = array();
$items[0] = new InvoiceItem();
$items[0]
    ->setUnitOfMeasure('Amount')
    ->setName("Sutures")
    ->setQuantity(1)
    ->setUnitPrice(new Currency());

$items[0]->getUnitPrice()
    ->setCurrency("EUR")
    ->setValue(99); // 1 EUR
```

**NOTE: Even if you are using the `Unit of Measurement Amount`, you are still to use `setQuantity`**

And that fixed my problem. I hope it will fix someone's else.

Good luck!